# How can i set git webhooks+jenkins

Tags: gitlab, jenkins-plugins, gitlab-api

I refer to a lot of examples, but web hooks are not configured successfully, I do not know why? The URLs in the web hooks have also tried various situations, but they have always been 500 error.

Gitlab version : 10.6.2-ee

Jenkins version:2.83

Gitlab plugin: 1.5.4

Gitlab Hook plugin: 1.4.2

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Error 500` means the server misbehaved.
You need to check the GitLab server logs to see the exact nature of the exception mentioned by the GitLab server.

It could be an authentication (token) issue, as reported in [gitlab-ce issue 34143](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/34143).

The [OP blue](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5518642/blue) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49621133/how-can-i-set-git-webhooksjenkins/49622383#comment86291490_49622383):

> [...] because the GitLab and Jenkins services are not on a network segment.
>
> There is also an open configuration "Allow requests to the local network from hooks and services"

That was mentioned in [jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin issue 272](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/272#issuecomment-377143149)

> You have to enable "Allow requests to the local network from hooks and services" in Setting page in Gitlab with new updates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have already solved this problem, mainly because the Gitlab and jenkins services are not on a network segment. This problem is easy to ignore. There is also an open configuration "Allow requests to the local network from hooks and services"

Comment: @blue Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. And I have added a link to a relevant issue.